# .NET Core SignalR - Chrome and Firefox stop displaying updates from server after 30-40 mins

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, websocket, signalr

I have an AngularJS application with a .NET Core back-end, using an Nginx server, and I'm using the following front-end SignalR library:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/microsoft-signalr/3.1.3/signalr.min.js

The application works fine, however after about 30-40 mins, the following error appears in the console, and the client no longer displays any real-time messages. I need to refresh the browser for it to work again. This occurs on both Chrome and Firefox:

`Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: WebSocket closed with status code: 1006 ()`

[image]

I've looked at these questions, but they haven't solved my issue:

[getting the reason why websockets closed with close code 1006](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19304157/getting-the-reason-why-websockets-closed-with-close-code-1006)

[SignalR Core - Error: Websocket closed with status code: 1006](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53944572/signalr-core-error-websocket-closed-with-status-code-1006)

I've tried:

- Setting the following configuration settings on Nginx

  `proxy_read_timeout 86400s;`

  `proxy_send_timeout 86400s;`
- Installing a websockets service in Nginx (that seems to at least be giving me a websocket connection - and I've verified that it's using `wss`):
  [image]
- Restarting the client hub after it closes:

  ```
  hub.deviceHub.onclose(async () => {
      console.log("restarting hub connection after it was closed");
      await hub.StartConnection;
  });
  ```

None of this fixes the issue. What could be causing this, and what else could I try?

I have a related question here about the SignalR connection completing failing at the back-end after about 2 weeks - this provides more detail about the way the back-end is set up:

[Server-side SignalR connection fails after significant uptime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62187401/server-side-signalr-connection-fails-after-significant-uptime)

Comment: You can try to turn the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR` logging to `Trace` level and check if there is more information there.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be an issue in the back end. The back end SignalR connection would drop and restart around every 40mins or so. When restarting the connection, I was re-using the existing connection. Now, I create a completely new connection at the backend before reconnecting. See this answer from @Mark Feldman for the solution to my issue - https://stackoverflow.com/a/63277203/1549918.